# How to select a specific tab in a TabBarController from a UIViewController WHICH ISN'T one of the tabs?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I've spent a good hour researching this issue and can't figure it out despite scouring SO.  Basically, I have a TabBarController (TBC) with several tabs each with an associated UIViewController.  In my app I ***also have*** other UIViewControllers which are not at all part of the TBC.  I have a button on one of these non-TBC UIViewControllers that, when clicked, should not only navigate to the TBC but also a specific tab index that is not 0.

I have found lots of people saying, "oh just reference self.tabBarController...blah blah blah" but self doesn't work for me when I'm in one of my non-TBC UIViewControllers.

I did find the following which I thought might work but didn't.  The code gets a reference to the TBC I need, assigns a non-zero index in anticipation of its display, and then performs a segue.  Unfortunately, I continue to only see the first tab following the segue.

```
// doesn't work...    
UITabBarController *TBC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TBC"];
TBC.selectedIndex = 1;
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goTBC" sender:nil];
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this issue by creating an int variable in my AppDelegate to track what tab index should be displayed with a default to 0.  Then, in my TabBarController's viewWillAppear method I set the selectedIndex to the tab index I have stored in AppDelegate.  This takes care of the problem albeit in a way that I don't think is the cleanest it could be.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     // Assume ad is your app delegate...
     // Assume navToIndex is the int I referenced above in app delegate
     self.selectedIndex = ad.navToIndex;
}
```